Find the image of the region $D$
Task: Find the image of the region $D$ when displayed by a fractional linear function $w=f(z)$ satisfying the specified condition: $f(1) = -1, f(i) = 0, f(-1) = 1, D = \{z: \mathrm{Im}(z)<0\}$. Using the formula, I found the function $$w = \frac{z-i}{iz-1} = \frac{1}{i} - \frac{2i}{z+i}.$$ I need to show graphically, so I did this:

$z: \mathrm{Im}(z)<0$ - initially I have an imaginary area below zero.
$w_1: z + i$ - just raised the area to $i$.
$w_2: 2/w1$ - this is where I started having difficulties, I don't understand what happens to the area when we divide $2$ by it. Will there be a circle (if so, how and why)?
$w_3: 1/i - w_2$ - I realized that multiplying by $i$ would turn $90^\circ$ counterclockwise, but what to do when dividing $1$ by $i$?

Please explain how 3) and 4) will look graphically. I really need help. I think if I figure out how to do this, I can do the rest of the tasks.

This is mainly going to boil down to understanding $z\to\frac 1z.$  Because $\frac 1i$ is just a constant,  so adding it just raises the graph by $\frac 1i=-i.$

All $\frac 1z$ does is swap the interior and exterior of the unit disk.

Also what does multiplication by $2i$ do?  It rotates by an angle $\pi/2,$ since $i=e^{\pi/2i},$ and stretches by a factor of $2.$

So, let's follow/ break down what happens to $z.$
First:   add $i.$  This shifts the graph vertically by one.
Second:   invert, or apply $\frac 1z.$  This swaps interior and exterior of the unit circle.
Third:  multiply by $-2i.$  This stretches by a factor of $2$ and rotates by $3\pi/ 2.$  The rotation is because $-i=e^{3\pi i/2}.$
Finally: add $1/i=-i.$  Shift back down by a unit.

From this you can,  if you're very careful,  establish that any point in the lower half plane,  your region $D,$ winds up exterior to the unit disk.
You can also,  for any such point- exterior to the unit disk- find a point in $D$ that goes there.

Hint: since in addition $f(0)=i,$ we can conclude that the real axis goes to the unit circle.
Then, the lower half plane by continuity must go to either the interior or exterior of that circle.   Use a test point.   $f(i)=0$ implies it goes to the exterior.
Remark:  this is the inverse of the famous Cayley transform.
